# Using Data annotation on Java DTO class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto, lombok

I have confusion in using Data annotation to DTO class. Here is my sample class.

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}
```

I've read online that using Data annotation specifically on DTO class will allow the values of the fields to be changed by use of the generated setters.

Should I remove the lombok Data annotation? And implement the getters and setters manually.

Thanks :)

Comment: which @Data are you talking about? is it from Lombok?

Comment: A setter should update the content of a field. You have to decide if you want instances of that class to be immutable or not. It doesn't matter *how* setters are coming into your class, the only question: should there be setters? And that is a requirement that only *you* can decide how to go about it.

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid @Data for DTOs since it has too many pitfalls. First of all as you mentioned it is mutable which you don't really want for a DTO. And despite it being mutable, it implements equals() and hashCode() which is only asking for trouble.

You can use @Value for an immutable DTO. For an incoming DTO you may need to add `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties` to your lombok.config, which will allow libraries like jackson to deserialize to your POJO without a default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The annotation [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) comes from the Project Lombok which is designed to use reflection via annotations mostly. This annotation assures generation of all the setters, getters, a constructor with all the required arguments and overridden `Object::toString`, `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` methods.

Briefly said, this annotation "completes" a simple POJO object and generates all the boilerplate without a need to use IDE.

They named the annotation `@Data` because they support the idea of the understanding objects as data containers only.

---

As far as I understand, the generation happens only for the missing getters/setters (let's speak about them for brevity). The generated getters/setters are in their pure form as you know:

```
public int getId() { return this.id; }

public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
```

You can use more verbose setter/getter performing validation or anything similar which override the generated ones. You can both use `@Data` annotation and write your ones manually.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas. Should I remove it and implement the getters and setters? so that it will prevent the values of the fields to be changed by use of the generated setters.

Comment: They will not be changed. The generated setters just complete the missing ones.

Answer (score 3):

By default the `@Data` lombok annotation will generate setters and getters for all fields in the class.

If you want an immutable data transfer object, annotate it as `@Value` instead.

If you want a mixure of some immmutable values and some mutable values in your `MyClass` type, for instance you might want the id field to be immutable and the rest mutable, you would use the `@Setter` annotation on the field you want to be immutable, specifying an `AccessLevel` of `NONE`. For instance:

```java
@Data
public class MyClass {
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}
```

This will generate a getter but no setter for the id, and a getter and setter for the name.

Answer (score 2):

DTO is used to transmit data information, some information is actually we do not want users to be able to change or access, such as the user password, we do not want to pass to the front end when the user can see the encrypted password, or we do not want users to modify the password while changing their information, and what works in this serialization process is setter and getter, and data annotations that automatically generate getters and setters for all fields.

For example

```
@Data
class User{

private String userName;

private String pwd;
}
```

This class, will have all setter and getter. When you trans to web, you will see

```
{userName: "123", pwd: "xxx"}
```

This is terrible.
But if you use DTO

```
class User{

private String userName;

private String pwd;

public String getUserName(){
    return userName;
}
}
```

They only see

```
{userName: "123"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **Java 14** you can use a `record` for your DTOs:

```java
public record MyClass(Long id, String name) {}
```